# Cómo podría hacer una prueba unitaria de este código en PHP

Tags: php, html, phpunit

No entiendo muy bien que hace el código si alguien podría echarme una mano a saber que hacer y realizar unas pruebas unitarias. En concreto no se que hacen !isset() y esta parte del codigo --> trim(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST[$valor], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")

```
<?php

$cadenaNombre = valorFormulario("nombre");
$cadenaApe = valorFormulario("apellidos");


function valorFormulario($valor, $aux = ""){

    if (!isset($_GET[$valor])) {

        $aux2 = (is_array($aux)) ? [] : "";
    } elseif (!is_array($_GET[$valor])) {

        $aux2 = trim(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST[$valor], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
    } else {

        $aux2 = $_GET[$valor];
        array_walk_recursive($aux2, function (&$valor2) {
        $valor2 = trim(htmlspecialchars($valor2, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
        });
    }
    return $aux2;
}


print "<p>El nombre introducido es $cadenaNombre.</p>\n";
print "\n";
print "<p>Elapellidointroducidoes $cadenaApe.</p>\n";
print "\n";
```

Comment: [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php) hace exactamente lo que dice que hace, comprueba si la variable está seteada/definida. Lo otro se le llama sanitizar el input. Se hace para evitar que el usuario inyecte código en un formulario. Cuando no sabes lo que hace un método "oficial" lo normal es irse a la documentación! Aquí tienes la de [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.htmlspecialchars). Y no le tengas miedo a las documentaciones, que no muerden... Mitad de nuestro trabajo es leer documentación en realidad :)

Answer (score 1):

La función [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php) evalúa la variable que se le pasa y determina si está definida o no. El símbolo `!` indica negación, por lo que la condición valúa si `$_GET[$valor]` no está definido. La función [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.htmlspecialchars) convierte caracteres especiales en entidades HTML, en donde el modificador `ENT_QUOTES` sirve para indicarle a la función que convierta comillas simples y dobles, mientras que `UTF-8` establece la codificación para la conversión de caracteres. Finalmente, la función [trim](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.trim) elimina espacios en blanco al inicio y al final de la cadena que se le pasa.

Siempre que tengas dudas con las funciones de PHP, puedes buscar sobre ellas en [el manual oficial](https://www.php.net/manual/es/).

Comment: Tecnicamente, esto no responde a su pregunta puesto que no has hecho ni mención a las pruebas unitarias! Esto suele pasar cuando se intenta responder una pregunta mal planteada o sin trabajo de investigación... Y ese tipo de preguntas, por regla general, no se responden, si no que se le indica que debe mejorarla y se cierra! Recuerda que aquí estamos para ayudar, no para hacerle los deberes a nadie. Por cierto, *negarse a buscar en la documentación* no está considerado "tener un problema", así que técnicamente esta pregunta no es muy correcta digamos

Comment: @Benito-B Estoy respondiendo a lo que pregunta en la descripción, estimado. Solo le di una concisa orientación sobre las funciones por las que pregunta, y al final le señalo que mejor consulte el manual. Eso es todo. Eso no es *hacerle la tarea*. Entiendo la intención de mantener un nivel en la página con respecto a las preguntas que formulan, pero hay que tener un poco más de criterio antes de caer en el simplismo de cerrar preguntas cuando no siempre es necesario hacerlo. A veces una respuesta que no implique *hacerle la tarea* puede ser de ayuda para quienes vienen por aquí. Un saludo.